# How to use data binding in the SystemTray when using Caliburn Micro?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I am converting a WP8, MVVM based app over to Caliburn Micro, which I'm brand new to (and pretty green to XAML/WP8 too)

I am stumped on how to bind things like the SystemTray to my view's ViewModel. Before Caliburn Micro, my views looked like

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModels:SomeViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
    <shell:ProgressIndicator IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsLoading, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" />
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

This worked very well and would show the loading indicator while the ViewModel was loading. Now that my ViewModel is no longer a StaticResource in the view, how do I get the binding up into the SystemTray?

My initial stab failed:

```
<shell:ProgressIndicator IsVisible="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.IsLoading" />
```

I feel like I need to pull the viewmodel out of `LayoutRoot` but am unsure how to do that.

Comment: This blog post has a different approach that looks like it will work: http://caraulean.com/blog/2011/12/09/using-wp7s-progressindicator-with-caliburn-micro/

I'm still generally curious how to solve the above with CM if anyone is game to answer.